# Merge two Pandas DataFrames on their DatetimeIndex columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation, datetimeindex

I am trying to merge two Pandas DataFrames on DatetimeIndex columns.  Each df contains different daily measurement data for an overlapping period, one day with several columns per line.  I want to end up with a df merged on the DatetimeIndex with still one day per line (`'inner'`), and all measurement columns of the original two dfs, but a single column for the common dates.  This works with `pd.merge()` as long as the dates are strings, but when I convert them to datetimes, `pd.merge()` tells me to use `pd.concat()` instead.  A minimal working example would look like this:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range('2022-01-02','2022-01-04'), columns=['dtm'])
df1['var1'] = np.random.random(len(df1))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range('2022-01-01','2022-01-05'), columns=['dtm'])
df2['var2'] = np.random.random(len(df2))*100

print(pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, join='inner'))
```

However, this gives me

```
         dtm      var1        dtm       var2
0 2022-01-02  0.942075 2022-01-01  82.021265
1 2022-01-03  0.857628 2022-01-02  62.548033
2 2022-01-04  0.432774 2022-01-03   3.883448
```

i.e., there are **two** `dtm` columns, and their dates are offset.  How can I tell `pd.concat()` to merge on the `dtm` columns?

Comment: What is your merge solution which failed?

Answer (score 0):

Create `DatetimeIndex` in both DataFrames:

```
print(pd.concat([df1.set_index('dtm'),df2.set_index('dtm')], axis=1, join='inner'))
                var1       var2
dtm                            
2022-01-02  0.801879  81.125161
2022-01-03  0.473338  89.862602
2022-01-04  0.950536  63.681588
```

For me `merge` working correct (columns `dtm` in both DataFrames are filled by datetimes):

```
print(df1.merge(df2, on='dtm'))

         dtm      var1       var2
0 2022-01-02  0.875464  11.180980
1 2022-01-03  0.282619  73.407783
2 2022-01-04  0.802322  88.379740
```